# Is it possible to dynamically exclude vertices from a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, boost-graph

I have a robotics project with multiple robots driving around along waypoints.
And I also have a graph which is consisting of vertices as waypoints.

So if I want to move to a target waypoint, I get a list of all the waypoints which are needed to go there.

Then I want to move another robot, and it's path is crossing the path of the first robot. And this situation I want to detect and block the algorithm to return a valid path or a shortened path till the last free waypoint before the crossing.

Should I customize the graph search algorithm or is it better to have another "reservation" layer which cuts the returned path?

I am new to this topic and I am wondering if this type of customization is possible in the boost graph library.

Comment: Yes. Use the `filtered_graph` adapter.  I have several examples - simple and advanced -  [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20filtered_graph)